# Targeting an element nested in two div classes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Sometimes working with wordpress can be a pain. Im trying to style a menu that is generated by wordpress.

here is the basic html

```
<div class="footer">
  <!--Generated By Wordpress-->
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item">
      <a></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!--End Generated-->
</div>
```

I want to create some CSS to target specifically the <a> within the sub menu, without messing with the <a> in the main menu. Also I cant mess with any other menus I have set up on the site, so this also must be specific to the footer menu.

Would this be the proper method?

```
.footer .sub-menu a { }
```

What would be the proper method for this?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did something go wrong? Otherwise, it seems fine!

Comment: Wordpress [Menu Item CSS Classes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are right the following ways are appropriate:

**1**

```
.footer .sub-menu a{}
```

**2**

```
.footer ul.sub-menu a{}
```

**3**

```
ul.sub-menu a{}
```

Comment: thanks! Just double checking... it just felt wrong somehow :D